# Regex not to start with "."

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for file name validation. Here it is:

```
 /^[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_; ]+$/
```

How do I change it to check for file name not to start with `.` symbol. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will be the easiest solution:

```
/^(?!\.)[0-9a-zA-Z^&'@{}[\],$=!\-#().%+~_; ]+$/
```

Alternatively, you can match the first character with an extra character class:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z^&'@{}[\],$=!\-#()%+~_; ][0-9a-zA-Z^&'@{}[\],$=!\-#().%+~_; ]*$/
                               ^^ no dot here
```

Btw, inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) nearly all special characters loose their function and will not need to be escaped.